# "Error resolving template" when deploying app on Heroku

Tags: java, spring, maven, heroku

Here's my project structure:

```
├ pom.xml
├ Procfile
├ src
│  ├─ main
│  │   ├ java
│  │   │   └ spring
│  │   │       └ tests
│  │   │           ├ Application.java
│  │   │           └ GreetingController.java
│  │   └ resources
│  │       └ templates
│  │           └ index.html
```

`Application` is a simple `SpringApplication` that contains a main method that runs it:

```
SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
```

The `GreetingController` contains:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index() {
    return "index";
}
```

When I build the project using `maven` and **run it locally**:

```
java -Dserver.port=8080 -jar  target/*.jar
```

**everything works as expected**, and the `index` template gets loaded. However, when I deploy it to [Heroku](https://dashboard.heroku.com/), I get:

```
TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "index"
```

My `Procfile` is pretty simple:

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar  target/*.jar
```

Why does it work fine locally but fails to load on Heroku? (I followed almost all related Stack Overflow questions, none of them worked for me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in my `index.html` file. I had:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

For some reason, it worked locally, but threw an exception when running from Heruko. The solution was changing `http` to `https`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
                 ↑
```